# Как исправить двусмысленное предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Археологи заметили, что покойники из южного захоронения перекликаются с покойниками из северного захоронения.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь Ушакова

Перекликаться

перекликаться, перекликаюсь, перекликаешься, несовер.

1. (совер. перекликнуться) с кем-чем. Издали криком давать о себе знать друг другу. «В лесу, казалось, шел говор тысячи могучих, хотя и глухих голосов, о чем-то грозно перекликавшихся во мраке.» Короленко. Девушки перекликались в лесу.
2. (совер. нет) перен. Стоять в связи с чем-нибудь, образовывать какую-нибудь общность между собой, единую связывающую линию, вследствие близости, сходства в чем-нибудь (книж.). Некоторые образы поэзии Лермонтова перекликаются с байроновскими образами.
3. страд. к перекликать (разг.).

Нас интересует п. 2. Нужно просто использовать синонимы, вот некоторые из них:  походят (похожи), напоминают (в них что-то напоминает о), (в чем-то) сходны, в них что-то есть от.

Answer (score 1):

Археологи заметили сходство между погребёнными в северном и южном захоронениях.

Comment: Коротко и ясно. И *погребенные* в этом контексте правильней, чем *покойники*.

Comment: Речь здесь идет о типе погребения.

Comment: Точнее, о типе, характере захоронений - сопоставлении их.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы исправить стилистически дефектную фразу, надо, во-первых, определить вид, причину речевой ошибки, а, во-вторых, установить, что именно хотел сказать автор высказывания, при этом сохраняя стиль, речевой регистр изложения.

В данном случае мы имеем дело сразу с несколькими речевыми ошибками: 1) смешение научного и разговорного стилей (выражения «археологи установили», «южное захоронение», «северное захоронение» относятся к научному стилю, слово «покойники» - к разговорному); 2) употребление выражения, вызывающего неуместные ассоциации («покойники перекликаются»); 3) речевая избыточность в в сочетании с речевой недостаточностью  (сказано лишнее, но не сказано необходимое – о типе, характере захоронения); 4) неточность словоупотребления (следует говорить не о «перекличке», но о сходстве, тождестве, аналогии: это совершенно правильно отмечено в ответе М_Г  и воплощено в ответе Alex_anderа).

Что же хотел сказать автор?  Он хотел выразить мысль о сходстве, аналогичности характера южного и северного захоронений.

Мой вариант правки: АРХЕОЛОГИИ УСТАНОВИЛИ, ЧТО ЮЖНОЕ И СЕВЕРНОЕ ЗАХОРОНЕНИЕ АНАЛОГИЧНЫ ПО СВОЕМУ ХАРАКТЕРУ (ОТНОСЯТСЯ К ОДНОМУ ТИПУ).

Примечание: в данном случае  более предпочтительно употребить слово «аналогичны», так как оно более соответствует по своей окраске научному стилю, чем слово «сходны»,